# Tailwind css overflow dropdown issue

Tags: tailwind-css

What is the best way to get a dropdown showing its full height with rounded corner table?

There are suggestions that overflow-hidden should be removed. But if it is removed the rounded corner is looking ugly. Without overflow-hidden, the dropdown is hidden after the table length.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/gZeMiyEPmm

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest solution that I've found would be to remove`overflow-hidden` and add `sm:rounded-[xy]-lg` (where x is `b` or `t` and y is `l` or `r`) to proper `th`s and `td`s.

To simplify things I think that it would be easier to just add this to your css:

```css
table thead tr th:first-of-type {
  @apply sm:rounded-tl-lg;
}

table thead tr th:last-of-type {
  @apply sm:rounded-tr-lg;
}

table tbody tr:last-of-type td:first-of-type {
    @apply sm:rounded-bl-lg;
}

table tbody tr:last-of-type td:last-of-type {
    @apply sm:rounded-br-lg;
}
```

Comment: for some reason the border radius on the bottom right doesnt get applied, any idea why?

Comment: Well, I copied my answer to [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/JToX8AzYcg?file=css) and it works as expected, so the problem must be elsewhere than the code I provided